# Show input from textfields in a table

Tags: iphone, xcode

In the app I'm making I need to be able to store input from textfields, then show them in a table view with the ability, for the user, to delete or edit the input, and add more.

I have already made it possible to press a button -> next view, insert numbers and choose whatever option you want, and then press ADD. But I have no idea how to store and show the input.

The app is supposed to work this way:

You open the app, and you can press a PLUS sign. Then you are taken to a modal-view where get the option to choose from a slider, and input two different numbers in two textfields. Then press ADD. After the ADD-button is pressed, you are then taken to the first view, and the numbers and option you chose from the slider are then shown in a table view, with yet another plus sign beneath. So you can repeat the whole thing over and over.

After the above, there will be a "Calculate" button, where it calculates the different inputs, and gives an end result, but I will try and figure that one out myself, when I get the basic stuff working.

I'm looking forward to your answers, and I hope you will explain things thoroughly, as I am new at this field.

And please, don't just redirect me to  , I have read a lot, but nothing that covered my problem. And I'm not that good at figuring out things myself, based on e.g. Apple's own reference library .

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need someway to store all that info. If you need to sort or query against it in any way, use SQLite or you could use Core Data, but I never have.

More simply, you could instantiate an NSMutableArray, and make it property of the parent view, and when you push the child view to add the info, add a custom object that holds your info, and add it to the array. Tables are quite easy to use with array's, then implement the table methods to rearrange and delete them.

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

As far as calculating out totals or whatever, just loop through all the objects in that array, and do whatever you need to.

EDIT:

Example of a custom class:

```
MyClass
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *infoString1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *infoString2;
@property (nonatomic) int sliderValue;
```

How you could store the info

```
MyClass *object1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
object1.infoString1 = textField.text;
object1.infoString2 = textField2.text;
object1.sliderValue = [theSlider.value intValue] //Dont think thats correct code, but you get the idea
[parentView.theArray addObject:object1];
// then dismiss the view
```

Comment: Okay, that sounds like a plan, others have also told me that NSMutableArray was the way to go, but I've never figured out just how I use that. And if I were to create a custom object that holds the info of box a (first input) and another that holds info of box b (second input) and so on, how do I get the info from the textfields into that object.

Comment: customObject.info = textfield.text;  It would be a good idea to spend some time looking at the documentation for UITextField and NSMutableArray.  You could find answers to most of these questions in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Dancreek I know of the documentation, and I've read a lot of it. But I still find it hard to implement the code. I'm new to Objective-C, and haven't coded a lot before (programming) and there are not a lot of "well-written" guides out there, that explains every little move, from implementing the code in the right files (.m / .h) importing the class and so on.